# Issue while configuration WowzaStreamingEngine LoadBalancer_4.0

Tags: streaming, load-balancing, wowza

I got error with loadbalancer_4.0 plugin added in wowzasteamingengine:

can any one suggest me what was wrong and help me to solve out this issue.

i got this error---->

```
    2015-07-27  11:22:22    IST comment server  ERROR   500 -   Encrypter:Decrypt() Error decrypting message: '<html><head><title>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Trial Edition (Expires: Dec 09, 2015) 4.2.0 build15089</title></head><body>Wowza Streaming Engine 4 Trial Edition (Expires: Dec 09, 2015) 4.2.0 build15089</body></html>, : java.lang.NullPointerException|at com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.encoders.Thor.decrypt(Thor.java:74)|at com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.encoders.Encrypter.decrypt(Encrypter.java:106)|at com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.general.XMLParser.xmlParse(XMLParser.java:55)|at com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.general.URLHandler.clientConnectionURL(URLHandler.java:73)|at com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.monitors.LoadBalanceBandwidthMonitorClient.run(LoadBalanceBandwidthMonitorClient.java:144)|
```

my server.xml -------->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Root version="2">
<Server>
    <Name>Wowza Streaming Engine</Name>
    <Description>Wowza Streaming Engine is robust, customizable, and scalable server software that powers reliable streaming of high-quality video and audio to any device, anywhere.</Description>
    <RESTInterface>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
        <IPAddress>*</IPAddress>
        <Port>8087</Port>
        <!-- none, basic, digest-->
        <AuthenticationMethod>digest</AuthenticationMethod>
        <DiagnosticURLEnable>true</DiagnosticURLEnable>
        <SSLConfig>
            <Enable>false</Enable>
            <KeyStorePath></KeyStorePath>
            <KeyStorePassword></KeyStorePassword>
            <KeyStoreType>JKS</KeyStoreType>
            <SSLProtocol>TLS</SSLProtocol>
            <Algorithm>SunX509</Algorithm>
            <CipherSuites></CipherSuites>
            <Protocols></Protocols>
        </SSLConfig>
        <IPWhiteList>127.0.0.1</IPWhiteList>
        <IPBlackList></IPBlackList>
        <EnableXMLFile>false</EnableXMLFile>
        <DocumentationServerEnable>false</DocumentationServerEnable>
        <DocumentationServerPort>8089</DocumentationServerPort>
        <!-- none, basic, digest-->
        <DocumentationServerAuthenticationMethod>digest</DocumentationServerAuthenticationMethod>
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </RESTInterface>
    <CommandInterface>
        <HostPort>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
            <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
            <Port>8083</Port>
        </HostPort>
    </CommandInterface>
    <AdminInterface>
        <!-- Objects exposed through JMX interface: Server, VHost, VHostItem, Application, ApplicationInstance, MediaCaster, Module, Client, MediaStream, SharedObject, Acceptor, IdleWorker -->
        <ObjectList>Server,VHost,VHostItem,Application,ApplicationInstance,MediaCaster,Module,IdleWorker</ObjectList>
    </AdminInterface>
    <Stats>
        <Enable>true</Enable>
    </Stats>
    <!-- JMXUrl: service:jmx:rmi://localhost:8084/jndi/rmi://localhost:8085/jmxrmi -->
    <JMXRemoteConfiguration>
        <Enable>false</Enable>
        <IpAddress>localhost</IpAddress> <!-- set to localhost or internal ip address if behind NAT -->
        <RMIServerHostName>localhost</RMIServerHostName> <!-- set to external ip address or domain name if behind NAT -->
        <RMIConnectionPort>8084</RMIConnectionPort>
        <RMIRegistryPort>8085</RMIRegistryPort>
        <Authenticate>true</Authenticate>
        <PasswordFile>${com.wowza.wms.ConfigHome}/conf/jmxremote.password</PasswordFile>
        <AccessFile>${com.wowza.wms.ConfigHome}/conf/jmxremote.access</AccessFile>
        <SSLSecure>false</SSLSecure>
    </JMXRemoteConfiguration>
    <UserAgents>Shockwave Flash|CFNetwork|MacNetwork/1.0 (Macintosh)</UserAgents>
    <Streams>
        <DefaultStreamPrefix>mp4</DefaultStreamPrefix>
    </Streams>
    <ServerListeners>
        <ServerListener>
            <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.mediacache.impl.MediaCacheServerListener</BaseClass>
        </ServerListener>
        <ServerListener>
            <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.general.LoadBalancerServer</BaseClass>
        </ServerListener>
        <!--
        <ServerListener>
            <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.ServerListenerLoadBalancerListener</BaseClass>
        </ServerListener>
        -->
        <!--
        <ServerListener>
            <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.ServerListenerLoadBalancerSender</BaseClass>
        </ServerListener>
        -->
    </ServerListeners>
    <VHostListeners>
        <!--
        <VHostListener>
            <BaseClass></BaseClass>
        </VHostListener>
        -->
    </VHostListeners> 
    <HandlerThreadPool>
        <PoolSize>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</PoolSize>
    </HandlerThreadPool>
    <TransportThreadPool>
        <PoolSize>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</PoolSize>
    </TransportThreadPool>
    <RTP>
        <DatagramStartingPort>6970</DatagramStartingPort>
        <DatagramPortSharing>false</DatagramPortSharing>
    </RTP>

    <Manager>
        <!-- Properties defined are used by the Manager -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Manager>

    <!-- Properties defined here will be added to the IServer.getProperties() collection -->
    <Properties>

        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceType</Name>
            <Value>Server,Client</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceKey</Name>
            <Value>123456789012345</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceServerIP</Name>
            <Value>192.168.2.91</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceServerPort</Name>
            <Value>1935</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceDecisionOrder</Name>
            <Value>Bandwidth,Connection</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceIgnoreClients</Name>
            <Value>FMLE</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceBandwidthEnable</Name>
            <Value>On</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceBandwidthLimit</Name>
            <Value>50000</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceConnectionEnable</Name>
            <Value>On</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>
        <Property>
            <Name>loadbalanceConnectionLimit</Name>
            <Value>100</Value>
            <Type>String</Type>
        </Property>

    </Properties>
</Server>
    </Root>
```

my vhost.xml ------>

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root version="2">
<VHost>
    <Description></Description>
    <HostPortList>
        <HostPort>
            <Name>Default Streaming</Name>
            <Type>Streaming</Type>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
            <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
            <!-- Separate multiple ports with commas -->
            <!-- 80: HTTP, RTMPT -->
            <!-- 554: RTSP -->
            <Port>1935</Port>
            <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
            <SocketConfiguration>
                <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
                <!-- suggested settings for video on demand applications -->
                <ReceiveBufferSize>65000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <ReadBufferSize>65000</ReadBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>65000</SendBufferSize>
                <!-- suggest settings for low latency chat and video recording applications
                <ReceiveBufferSize>32000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <ReadBufferSize>32000</ReadBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>32000</SendBufferSize>
                -->
                <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
                <!-- <TrafficClass>0</TrafficClass> -->
                <!-- <OobInline>false</OobInline> -->
                <!-- <SoLingerTime>-1</SoLingerTime> -->
                <!-- <TcpNoDelay>false</TcpNoDelay> -->
                <AcceptorBackLog>100</AcceptorBackLog>
            </SocketConfiguration>
            <HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>cupertinostreaming,smoothstreaming,sanjosestreaming,dvrchunkstreaming,mpegdashstreaming</HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>
            <HTTPProviders>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPCrossdomain</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*crossdomain.xml</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPClientAccessPolicy</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*clientaccesspolicy.xml</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPProviderMediaList</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*jwplayer.rss|*jwplayer.smil|*medialist.smil|*manifest-rtmp.f4m</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.timedtext.http.HTTPProviderCaptionFile</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*.ttml|*.srt|*.scc|*.vtt</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>

                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.http.LoadBalancerPublicInterface</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>redirect*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.http.LoadBalancerInterface</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*loadbalancerInterface</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.http.LoadBalancerInformation</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*loadbalancerInfo</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>

            </HTTPProviders>
        </HostPort>

        <!-- 443 with SSL -->
        <!--
        <HostPort>
            <Name>Default SSL Streaming</Name>
            <Type>Streaming</Type>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
            <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
            <Port>443</Port>
            <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
            <SSLConfig>
                <KeyStorePath>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/conf/keystore.jks</KeyStorePath>
                <KeyStorePassword>[password]</KeyStorePassword>
                <KeyStoreType>JKS</KeyStoreType>
                <SSLProtocol>TLS</SSLProtocol>
                <Algorithm>SunX509</Algorithm>
                <CipherSuites></CipherSuites>
                <Protocols></Protocols>
            </SSLConfig>
            <SocketConfiguration>
                <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
                <ReceiveBufferSize>65000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <ReadBufferSize>65000</ReadBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>65000</SendBufferSize>
                <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
                <AcceptorBackLog>100</AcceptorBackLog>
            </SocketConfiguration>
            <HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>cupertinostreaming,smoothstreaming,sanjosestreaming,dvrchunkstreaming,mpegdashstreaming</HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>
            <HTTPProviders>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPCrossdomain</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*crossdomain.xml</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPClientAccessPolicy</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*clientaccesspolicy.xml</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPProviderMediaList</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*jwplayer.rss|*jwplayer.smil|*medialist.smil|*manifest-rtmp.f4m</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
            </HTTPProviders>
        </HostPort>
        -->

        <!-- Admin HostPort -->
        <HostPort>
            <Name>Default Admin</Name>
            <Type>Admin</Type>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
            <IpAddress>*</IpAddress>
            <Port>8086</Port>
            <HTTPIdent2Response></HTTPIdent2Response>
            <SocketConfiguration>
                <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
                <ReceiveBufferSize>16000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <ReadBufferSize>16000</ReadBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>16000</SendBufferSize>
                <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
                <AcceptorBackLog>100</AcceptorBackLog>
            </SocketConfiguration>
            <HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs></HTTPStreamerAdapterIDs>
            <HTTPProviders>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.streammanager.HTTPStreamManager</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>streammanager*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerInfoXML</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>serverinfo*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPConnectionInfo</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>connectioninfo*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPConnectionCountsXML</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>connectioncounts*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.transcoder.httpprovider.HTTPTranscoderThumbnail</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>transcoderthumbnail*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPProviderMediaList</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>medialist*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.livestreamrecord.http.HTTPLiveStreamRecord</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>livestreamrecord*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>admin-digest</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
                <HTTPProvider>
                    <BaseClass>com.wowza.wms.http.HTTPServerVersion</BaseClass>
                    <RequestFilters>*</RequestFilters>
                    <AuthenticationMethod>none</AuthenticationMethod>
                </HTTPProvider>
            </HTTPProviders>
        </HostPort>

    </HostPortList>

    <HTTPStreamerAdapters>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>smoothstreaming</ID>
            <Name>smoothstreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>cupertinostreaming</ID>
            <Name>cupertinostreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>sanjosestreaming</ID>
            <Name>sanjosestreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>dvrchunkstreaming</ID>
            <Name>dvrchunkstreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>mpegdashstreaming</ID>
            <Name>mpegdashstreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>tsstreaming</ID>
            <Name>tsstreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
        <HTTPStreamerAdapter>
            <ID>webmstreaming</ID>
            <Name>webmstreaming</Name>
            <Properties>
            </Properties>
        </HTTPStreamerAdapter>
    </HTTPStreamerAdapters>

    <!-- When set to zero, thread pool configuration is done in Server.xml -->
    <HandlerThreadPool>
        <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
    </HandlerThreadPool>
    <TransportThreadPool>
        <PoolSize>0</PoolSize>
    </TransportThreadPool>
    <IdleWorkers>
        <WorkerCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</WorkerCount>
        <CheckFrequency>50</CheckFrequency>
        <MinimumWaitTime>5</MinimumWaitTime>
    </IdleWorkers>
    <NetConnections>
        <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        <IdleFrequency>250</IdleFrequency>
        <SocketConfiguration>
            <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
            <ReceiveBufferSize>65000</ReceiveBufferSize>
            <ReadBufferSize>65000</ReadBufferSize>
            <SendBufferSize>65000</SendBufferSize>
            <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
            <!-- <TrafficClass>0</TrafficClass> -->
            <!-- <OobInline>false</OobInline> -->
            <!-- <SoLingerTime>-1</SoLingerTime> -->
            <!-- <TcpNoDelay>false</TcpNoDelay> -->
            <AcceptorBackLog>100</AcceptorBackLog>
        </SocketConfiguration>
    </NetConnections>
    <MediaCasters>
        <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        <SocketConfiguration>
            <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
            <ReceiveBufferSize>65000</ReceiveBufferSize>
            <ReadBufferSize>65000</ReadBufferSize>
            <SendBufferSize>65000</SendBufferSize>
            <KeepAlive>true</KeepAlive>
            <!-- <TrafficClass>0</TrafficClass> -->
            <!-- <OobInline>false</OobInline> -->
            <!-- <SoLingerTime>-1</SoLingerTime> -->
            <!-- <TcpNoDelay>false</TcpNoDelay> -->
            <ConnectionTimeout>10000</ConnectionTimeout>
        </SocketConfiguration>
    </MediaCasters>
    <LiveStreamTranscoders>
        <MaximumConcurrentTranscodes>0</MaximumConcurrentTranscodes>
    </LiveStreamTranscoders>
    <HTTPTunnel>
        <KeepAliveTimeout>2000</KeepAliveTimeout>
    </HTTPTunnel>
    <Client>
        <ClientTimeout>90000</ClientTimeout>
        <IdleFrequency>250</IdleFrequency>
    </Client>
    <!-- RTP/Authentication/Methods defined in Authentication.xml. Default setup includes; none, basic, digest -->
    <RTP>
        <IdleFrequency>75</IdleFrequency>
        <DatagramConfiguration>
            <Incoming>
                <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
                <ReceiveBufferSize>2048000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>65000</SendBufferSize>
                <!-- <MulticastBindToAddress>true</MulticastBindToAddress> -->
                <!-- <MulticastInterfaceAddress>192.168.1.22</MulticastInterfaceAddress> -->
                <!-- <TrafficClass>0</TrafficClass> -->
                <MulticastTimeout>50</MulticastTimeout>
                <DatagramMaximumPacketSize>4096</DatagramMaximumPacketSize>
            </Incoming>
            <Outgoing>
                <ReuseAddress>true</ReuseAddress>
                <ReceiveBufferSize>65000</ReceiveBufferSize>
                <SendBufferSize>256000</SendBufferSize>
                <!-- <MulticastBindToAddress>true</MulticastBindToAddress> -->
                <!-- <MulticastInterfaceAddress>192.168.1.22</MulticastInterfaceAddress> -->
                <!-- <TrafficClass>0</TrafficClass> -->
                <MulticastTimeout>50</MulticastTimeout>
                <DatagramMaximumPacketSize>4096</DatagramMaximumPacketSize>
            </Outgoing>
        </DatagramConfiguration>
        <UnicastIncoming>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        </UnicastIncoming>
        <UnicastOutgoing>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        </UnicastOutgoing>
        <MulticastIncoming>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        </MulticastIncoming>
        <MulticastOutgoing>
            <ProcessorCount>${com.wowza.wms.TuningAuto}</ProcessorCount>
        </MulticastOutgoing>
    </RTP>
    <Application>
        <ApplicationTimeout>60000</ApplicationTimeout>
        <PingTimeout>12000</PingTimeout>
        <UnidentifiedSessionTimeout>30000</UnidentifiedSessionTimeout>
        <ValidationFrequency>20000</ValidationFrequency>
        <MaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</MaximumPendingWriteBytes>
        <MaximumSetBufferTime>60000</MaximumSetBufferTime>
    </Application>
    <StartStartupStreams>true</StartStartupStreams>

    <Manager>
        <TestPlayer>
            <IpAddress>${com.wowza.wms.HostPort.IpAddress}</IpAddress>
            <Port>${com.wowza.wms.HostPort.FirstStreamingPort}</Port>
            <SSLEnable>${com.wowza.wms.HostPort.SSLEnable}</SSLEnable>
        </TestPlayer>
        <!-- Properties defined are used by the Manager -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Manager>

    <!-- Properties defined here will be added to the IVHost.getProperties() collection -->
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
</VHost>
  </Root>
```

my redirect(Application.xml) it's a vod type ---->

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <Root version="1">
<Application>
    <Name>redirect</Name>
    <AppType>VOD</AppType>
    <Description></Description>
    <!-- Uncomment to set application level timeout values
    <ApplicationTimeout>60000</ApplicationTimeout>
    <PingTimeout>12000</PingTimeout>
    <ValidationFrequency>8000</ValidationFrequency>
    <MaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</MaximumPendingWriteBytes>
    <MaximumSetBufferTime>60000</MaximumSetBufferTime>
    <MaximumStorageDirDepth>25</MaximumStorageDirDepth>
    -->
    <Connections>
        <AutoAccept>true</AutoAccept>
        <AllowDomains></AllowDomains>
    </Connections>
    <!--
        StorageDir path variables

        ${com.wowza.wms.AppHome} - Application home directory
        ${com.wowza.wms.ConfigHome} - Configuration home directory
        ${com.wowza.wms.context.VHost} - Virtual host name
        ${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome} - Virtual host home directory
        ${com.wowza.wms.context.Application} - Application name
        ${com.wowza.wms.context.ApplicationInstance} - Application instance name

    -->
    <Streams>
        <StreamType>default</StreamType>
        <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content</StorageDir>
        <KeyDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/keys</KeyDir>
        <!-- LiveStreamPacketizers (separate with commas): cupertinostreamingpacketizer, smoothstreamingpacketizer, sanjosestreamingpacketizer, mpegdashstreamingpacketizer, cupertinostreamingrepeater, smoothstreamingrepeater, sanjosestreamingrepeater, mpegdashstreamingrepeater, dvrstreamingpacketizer, dvrstreamingrepeater -->
        <LiveStreamPacketizers></LiveStreamPacketizers>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/Streams.xml for any streams types loaded by this application -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Streams>
    <Transcoder>
        <!-- To turn on transcoder set to: transcoder -->
        <LiveStreamTranscoder></LiveStreamTranscoder>
        <!-- [templatename].xml or ${SourceStreamName}.xml -->
        <Templates>${SourceStreamName}.xml,transrate.xml</Templates>
        <ProfileDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/transcoder/profiles</ProfileDir>
        <TemplateDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/transcoder/templates</TemplateDir>
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Transcoder>
    <DVR>
        <!-- As a single server or as an origin, use dvrstreamingpacketizer in LiveStreamPacketizers above -->
        <!-- Or, in an origin-edge configuration, edges use dvrstreamingrepeater in LiveStreamPacketizers above -->
        <!-- As an origin, also add dvrchunkstreaming to HTTPStreamers below -->
        <!-- If this is a dvrstreamingrepeater, define Application/Repeater/OriginURL to point back to the origin -->
        <!-- To turn on DVR recording set Recorders to dvrrecorder.  This works with dvrstreamingpacketizer  -->
        <Recorders></Recorders>
        <!-- As a single server or as an origin, set the Store to dvrfilestorage-->
        <!-- edges should have this empty -->
        <Store></Store>
        <!--  Window Duration is length of live DVR window in seconds.  0 means the window is never trimmed. -->
        <WindowDuration>0</WindowDuration>
        <!-- Storage Directory is top level location where dvr is stored.  e.g. c:/temp/dvr -->
        <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/dvr</StorageDir>
        <!-- valid ArchiveStrategy values are append, version, delete -->
        <ArchiveStrategy>append</ArchiveStrategy>
        <!-- Properties for DVR -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </DVR>
    <TimedText>
        <!-- VOD caption providers (separate with commas): vodcaptionprovidermp4_3gpp, vodcaptionproviderttml, vodcaptionproviderwebvtt,  vodcaptionprovidersrt, vodcaptionproviderscc -->
        <VODTimedTextProviders>vodcaptionprovidermp4_3gpp</VODTimedTextProviders>
        <!-- Properties for TimedText -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </TimedText>
    <!-- HTTPStreamers (separate with commas): cupertinostreaming, smoothstreaming, sanjosestreaming, mpegdashstreaming, dvrchunkstreaming -->
    <HTTPStreamers>sanjosestreaming, cupertinostreaming, smoothstreaming, mpegdashstreaming</HTTPStreamers>
    <MediaCache>
        <MediaCacheSourceList></MediaCacheSourceList>
    </MediaCache>
    <SharedObjects>
        <StorageDir>${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/applications/${com.wowza.wms.context.Application}/sharedobjects/${com.wowza.wms.context.ApplicationInstance}</StorageDir>
    </SharedObjects>
    <Client>
        <IdleFrequency>-1</IdleFrequency>
        <Access>
            <StreamReadAccess>*</StreamReadAccess>
            <StreamWriteAccess></StreamWriteAccess>
            <StreamAudioSampleAccess></StreamAudioSampleAccess>
            <StreamVideoSampleAccess></StreamVideoSampleAccess>
            <SharedObjectReadAccess>*</SharedObjectReadAccess>
            <SharedObjectWriteAccess>*</SharedObjectWriteAccess>
        </Access>
    </Client>
    <RTP>
        <!-- RTP/Authentication/[type]Methods defined in Authentication.xml. Default setup includes; none, basic, digest -->
        <Authentication>
            <PublishMethod>block</PublishMethod>
            <PlayMethod>none</PlayMethod>
        </Authentication>
        <!-- RTP/AVSyncMethod. Valid values are: senderreport, systemclock, rtptimecode -->
        <AVSyncMethod>senderreport</AVSyncMethod>
        <MaxRTCPWaitTime>12000</MaxRTCPWaitTime>
        <IdleFrequency>75</IdleFrequency>
        <RTSPSessionTimeout>90000</RTSPSessionTimeout>
        <RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>0</RTSPMaximumPendingWriteBytes>
        <RTSPBindIpAddress></RTSPBindIpAddress>
        <RTSPConnectionIpAddress>0.0.0.0</RTSPConnectionIpAddress>
        <RTSPOriginIpAddress>127.0.0.1</RTSPOriginIpAddress>
        <IncomingDatagramPortRanges>*</IncomingDatagramPortRanges>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/RTP.xml for any depacketizers loaded by this application -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </RTP>
    <MediaCaster>
        <RTP>
            <RTSP>
                <!-- udp, interleave -->
                <RTPTransportMode>interleave</RTPTransportMode>
            </RTSP>
        </RTP>
        <StreamValidator>
            <Enable>true</Enable>
            <ResetNameGroups>true</ResetNameGroups>
            <StreamStartTimeout>20000</StreamStartTimeout>
            <StreamTimeout>12000</StreamTimeout>
            <VideoStartTimeout>0</VideoStartTimeout>
            <VideoTimeout>0</VideoTimeout>
            <AudioStartTimeout>0</AudioStartTimeout>
            <AudioTimeout>0</AudioTimeout>
            <VideoTCToleranceEnable>false</VideoTCToleranceEnable>
            <VideoTCPosTolerance>3000</VideoTCPosTolerance>
            <VideoTCNegTolerance>-500</VideoTCNegTolerance>
            <AudioTCToleranceEnable>false</AudioTCToleranceEnable>
            <AudioTCPosTolerance>3000</AudioTCPosTolerance>
            <AudioTCNegTolerance>-500</AudioTCNegTolerance>
            <DataTCToleranceEnable>false</DataTCToleranceEnable>
            <DataTCPosTolerance>3000</DataTCPosTolerance>
            <DataTCNegTolerance>-500</DataTCNegTolerance>
            <AVSyncToleranceEnable>false</AVSyncToleranceEnable>
            <AVSyncTolerance>1500</AVSyncTolerance>
            <DebugLog>false</DebugLog>
        </StreamValidator>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaCasters.xml for any MediaCasters loaded by this applications -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </MediaCaster>
    <MediaReader>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaReaders.xml for any MediaReaders loaded by this applications -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </MediaReader>
    <MediaWriter>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/MediaWriter.xml for any MediaWriter loaded by this applications -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </MediaWriter>
    <LiveStreamPacketizer>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/LiveStreamPacketizers.xml for any LiveStreamPacketizers loaded by this applications -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </LiveStreamPacketizer>
    <HTTPStreamer>
        <!-- Properties defined here will override any properties defined in conf/HTTPStreamers.xml for any HTTPStreamer loaded by this applications -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </HTTPStreamer>
    <Manager>
        <!-- Properties defined are used by the Manager -->
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </Manager>
    <Repeater>
        <OriginURL></OriginURL>
        <QueryString><![CDATA[]]></QueryString>
    </Repeater>
    <StreamRecorder>
        <Properties>
        </Properties>
    </StreamRecorder>
    <Modules>
        <Module>
            <Name>base</Name>
            <Description>Base</Description>
            <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore</Class>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <Name>logging</Name>
            <Description>Client Logging</Description>
            <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging</Class>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <Name>flvplayback</Name>
            <Description>FLVPlayback</Description>
            <Class>com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback</Class>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <Name>Redirect</Name>
            <Description>Redirect</Description>
            <Class>com.wowza.wms.plugin.loadbalancer.redirect.ClientConnections</Class>
        </Module>
    </Modules>
    <!-- Properties defined here will be added to the IApplication.getProperties() and IApplicationInstance.getProperties() collections -->
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
</Application>
   </Root>
```

Please help me out to solve this issue

thanks in advance